# Are DMA DRQs the DMA virtual channels

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, driver, linux-device-driver, dma

I have few basic queries regarding DMA in Linux. In one of the [DTS file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/boot/dts/actions/s900.dtsi#L284) for instance for S900 SoC, I see total number of DMA channels are 12 but when I checked in

```
ls /sys/class/dma
```

I see total number of DAM channels are 46 (`dma0chan45`), does that mean DRQ's are also count as DMA channels ?

Also, I didn't quite get what are the DMA channels about and what is the difference between Virtual and Physical channel?

Comment: In straightforward design the amount of Dreq, Dack and DMA channels are equal, but in some cases hardware does optimizations (for example, m2m doesn't need any Dreq/Dack from peripheral). In this case it is an opposite, the amount of channels are less than request lines, so, more peripheral can use DMA, but only 12 at a time.

Comment: Virtual channel as a concept of Linux kernel or something else (in general)? In Linux kernel it's just a framework that manages queues of DMA descriptors.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy for your reply. is there documentation available regarding the way Virtual channels are used in Linux ?